# alguien que me puede ayudar mejorar la la consulta

Tags: php, sqlite

[image: quiero habilitar el dia 20 y el 28]

```html
public function getDiaLineas($id_productos, $id_lineas, $fecha) {
  $query = "SELECT count(a.id) total "
   . "FROM reservaciones a "
   . "LEFT JOIN productos b ON a.id_productos = b.id "
   . "WHERE a.id_productos>0 AND a.estado=1 AND a.tipo=1 "
   . "AND date('$fecha') BETWEEN date(a.fecha_checkout) AND (CASE WHEN a.fecha_checkin!='' THEN date(a.fecha_checkin) ELSE date(a.fecha_checkin_tmp) END) "
   . "AND (a.id_productos=? OR b.id_lineas=? )";
  $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
  $result->execute(array($id_productos, $id_lineas));
  while ($row = $result->fetchColumn()) {
   return $row;
  }
 }
```

aca le sume un dia a la fecha inicio y le reste un dia al a fecha final
pero como hay dos ocupaciones en el dia 24, entonces me lo habilita y eso no quiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso Checa el [tour] considera editar y explicar mejor tu duda

Comment: Y cómo son las tablas desde las que tomas los datos? Y qué datos de prueba pueden usar los que quieran probar tu consulta para mejorarla? Y cuál es la salida esperada? Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade la información relevante